# Block someone on my website?

Tags: javascript, web, block

I'd like to block someone from my website, specifically blocking thier IP address.  (Forgot to mention this is a tumblr blog........ Hahahaha.. Sorry..)

I've tried a free html blocker from "Free Hosted Scripts" but they still seem to get over the block, someone has told me it's possible to block them with Java script too!

I'm a total noob so I would really like someone who could point me in the right direction in the simplest way possible!
Big thanks in advance!!

Comment: Javascript is on the client side. Only your server know the client IP. It's easiest to block from the server (apache conf, php, jsp, etc…).

Answer (score 1):

Well in the hope his IP is static, you could make use of an ".htaccess" file and write the following:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.45.6.7
allow from all
```

123.45.6.7 being his IP address and put that ".htaccess" file in the root of your website.

Answer (score 0):

If by block, you mean prevent someone from connecting to your HTTP server(s) and using your site, then this has to be done server-side.  It cannot be done client-side.  For someone to run client-side code, they would have to first connect to your site and retrieve a page.

There are a few ways to achieve what you want.  One option is to block them at the firewall level.  If you have a malicious user, this is often the best option as their requests will never even make it to the HTTP server, reducing load.

If you want to show the user a message indicating that they are not allowed to view the page, you must configure your web server or application to return a 403 status code, indicating that the user does not have permission.